# Can't set Content-Type for MultipartBody.Part in OkHttp

Tags: android, okhttp, retrofit2

After struggling with this problem for a few hours I finally decided to ask for an advice here. 
I use Retrofit 2 for networking in my app. This is how my method in API interface for uploading images looks like:

```
@POST(UPLOAD_PHOTO)
@Multipart
Call<UploadPhotoResponse> uploadPhoto(@Header("X-Auth-Token") String token, @Path("post_id") int postId
        , @Part("photo\"; filename=\"cover.jpg\"") MultipartBody.Part photo, @Part("photo_thumb\"; filename=\"cover_thumb.jpg\" ") MultipartBody.Part photoThumb);
```

Ad this is how I call it:

```
    RequestBody photoBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"),bytePhoto);
    RequestBody thumbBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), byteThumb);
    MultipartBody.Part photoPart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("photo", photoFile.getName(), photoBody);
    MultipartBody.Part thumbPart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("photo_thumb", thumbFile.getName(), thumbBody);
    Call<UploadPhotoResponse> call = apiService
            .uploadPhoto(sessionToken, postId, photoPart, thumbPart);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<UploadPhotoResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<UploadPhotoResponse> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

My problem is that I'm getting error message from server because of incorrect body parameters. For some reson Content-Type for each part is set to "application/json" as you can see from the screen from Fiddler:
[Request body parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjv16.jpg)

The only discussion relevant to my problem I was albe to find is [Multipart request overriding content-type not working #1433](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1433)

But it is about content-type for request header, not for body part. 
Maybe someone faced similar problem with OkHttp, because now I cant thing of anything what can solve my issue excetp switching from this library for this particular request.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently experiencing the same issue, as I am trying to send a String and a picture, both should be multipart/form-data.

Here's how the interface looks like:

```
@Multipart
    @POST("photos/setPhotos")
    Observable<SetPhotoResponseWrapper> uploadPhoto(@Part("userHash") RequestBody userHash, @Part("photos[]") MultipartBody.Part file);
```

And how the objects are created:

```
RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

        MultipartBody.Part multipart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), reqFile);

        RequestBody userBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), userHash);
```

And here are the logs from okHttp:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userHash"
10-12 14:23:43.951 29991-30723/com.gigrev.gigkev D/OkHttp: Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
10-12 14:23:43.951 29991-30723/com.gigrev.gigkev D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8
10-12 14:23:43.951 29991-30723/com.gigrev.gigkev D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 32
10-12 14:23:43.952 29991-30723/com.gigrev.gigkev D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photos[]"
10-12 14:23:43.952 29991-30723/com.gigrev.gigkev D/OkHttp: Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
10-12 14:23:43.952 29991-30723/com.gigrev.gigkev D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
10-12 14:23:43.952 29991-30723/com.gigrev.gigkev D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 111
10-12 14:23:43.952 29991-30723/com.gigrev.gigkev D/OkHttp: {"headers":{"namesAndValues":["Content-Disposition","form-data; name=\"picture\"; filename=\"IMAG0203.jpg\""]}}
```

Since the backend doesn't accept json, I have to figure it out on my side. Did you manage to find a solution?

EDIT: I actually found a solution. Just updated the retrofit version and this is what I get in the logs now:

```
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userHash"
10-12 14:55:59.775 24479-25505/com.gigrev.gigkev D/OkHttp: Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
10-12 14:55:59.775 24479-25505/com.gigrev.gigkev D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8
10-12 14:55:59.775 24479-25505/com.gigrev.gigkev D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 32
10-12 14:55:59.775 24479-25505/com.gigrev.gigkev D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="picture"; filename="IMAG0204.jpg"
10-12 14:55:59.775 24479-25505/com.gigrev.gigkev D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data
10-12 14:55:59.775 24479-25505/com.gigrev.gigkev D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 848314
```

Retrofit version:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'
```